# How to know what version of Google Play Developer API version I am using? What are the steps to update the Google Play Developer API version to v3?

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

A few days ago I got to see one warning notification in my Google Play Console. It says that

> “We’ve discovered that you’re using an old version of the Google Play Developer API in your app. As of December 1, 2019, versions 1 and 2 of this API will no longer be available. Please upgrade to version 3 by then.”

[image]

But I can't figure out how am I even using the API or which version of the API I am using.

Please help me to get rid of this warning.
The documentations are not enough.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/03/changes-to-google-play-developer-api.html

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT I saw this link but I don't understand how to do it in my case. I am not using those things mentioned there.

Comment: Yes. I also do not found any helpful information from the link that @GOVINDDIXIT sent. Did you found any solution for this issue @Eco4ndly?

Comment: Not yet @JaydipKalkani , I'll let you know as soon as I find any.

Answer (score 0):

(I am not able to comment, so I am providing as answer)

Your post doesn't specify whether your app has a server component. But based on the error message I am assuming that it does. One way to know which version of the API you are querying is to log the outgoing API calls you are making, and your log should look similar in form to this: `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/...`. For example if you want to verify a subscription on your server side, you would call `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token`.

Notice that each of these paths has the substring `v3`. My guess is yours says something else. So identify where your app is making outgoing calls and log those.

If I misunderstand, please clarify in the comments and I will edit.